# PHP Web Service returning HTML characters as entities

Tags: php, android, json

I have a PHP web service which returns data in JSON format.
I have a custom backend to maintain the data. When I save a record via the backend I use htmlspecialchars() on string fields.

An example web service call would run this code:

```
$dbh = getConnection('read');

$sql = "SELECT Name, Location FROM Venues WHERE id = :venueID";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':venueID' => $venue));
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

header("Content-type: application/json");
print(json_encode(array('venues'=>$data)));
```

So lets assume that for the provided venue ID the name has a & in it. The web service is called by an Android application so in the application it is displayed as a & and not &

Questions:

1. Do I tweak the custom backend to not use htmlspecialchars? I am the only admin so the data going in is safe
2. Is there a way to run htmlspecialchars_decode on the resultset without looping through the results before I print the JSON?

Comment: Why are you html encoding stuff that is going into your database? You should encoding text you are putting into HMTL documents, NOT the raw data. Is changing the way you are doing this an option? If so, I will post it as an answer.

Comment: So I should not use htmlspecialchars during an insert, but only when I am displaying data on a web page?

Comment: I will post an answer fully explaining what I am saying.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer here is that you should not be html encoding data that is going into your database. You want the data in your database to be exactly what the user entered.

An engineer is not expecting data in the database to be escaped in any way. As you can see, doing this forces you to remember to unencode the data whenever you take it out of the database. The problem in your case, is that `htmlspecialchars` is never meant to be reversed as the browser takes care of that for you in its rendering of the HTML.

You would normally use HMTL escaping in PHP templates like so:

```
<?php
$db = //get database connection
$data = $db->read//....
?>
<div>
<?=htmlspecialchars($data)?>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, but this data is not for webpage consumption, it is for Android app, but I see what you are saying. I will insert the data raw

Comment: @andrewb That's exactly my point. You probably escaped HTML characters originally so you did not have to do it when you took the data out of your database as it was all going to HTML pages. Now that you need it elsewhere though, you are seeing the issue with doing that.